# Web Audio API - record all tab sounds

Tags: javascript, html, web-audio-api

Is there a way to intercept and record all sounds happening in a browser tab using Audio API or some other method.

Let's say I am watching simultaneously three YouTube videos in one tab, can I record that using Audio API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't really directly possible (for security and privacy reasons).  As a user, it's possible to set it up - by setting a loopback audio driver as your audio output driver for the YT tabs - but not in a totally automated way.

(This is a duplicate, btw - of [Cross application audio analysis with the Web Audio API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40811409/cross-application-audio-analysis-with-the-web-audio-api), et al.)

Answer (score -1):

You can use http://goldfirestudios.com/blog/104/howler.js-Modern-Web-Audio-Javascript-Library this javascript library.
This link has full documentation, features and usage. This library works great for games and audio-related web apps. Hope this will help you.

Comment: That wasn't really the question.

Comment: but with this library you can record multiple audio running on same time

Comment: Right, but it's not really going to help you intercept and capture the output of tabs.